# Text broken after changed font

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

Please help me this question. In my app, I used a special font to make the app more elegant.
I did change the font by those of code:

```
public static Typeface fontsStyle;

public static void setTypeFace(TextView tv, AssetManager asm){

    if(fontsStyle == null)
        fontsStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(asm, "fonts/VNI 08 Springtime2.ttf"); 
    tv.setTypeface(fontsStyle, Typeface.BOLD);
}
```

And my problem is the text broken when I display unicode character (Vietnamese).

[image]

I tried many fonts and it happen all times, even those of font support unicode.
Any help will be appreciate.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean broken? Like it becomes junk character?

Comment: please see on the image. It become rectangle

Comment: Try to get sure that the font contains the glyphs you wanna print.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean about "glyphs". But those of font can print the character on MS Office Word

Comment: Is the default font (system font) managed to display it correctly?

Comment: yes. By default font, It display correctly.

Comment: Can it help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15496217/693752

Comment: What @Snicolas said could be right about the glyphs (the one that tells the machine how to draw your character) not supported. But its funny if it is a vietnamese font that you used that does not support vietnamese character, unless it is not..

Comment: I run the app on Android 4.1, does it happen on later 4.0. Maybe I have the same problem.... Thank you @Snicolas

Comment: Tell me the hex value of the junk character, I check it against the code font you used.

Comment: this is "1EA4", please help me check.  :http://utf8-characters.com/latin-extended-additional/latin-capital-letter-a-with-circumflex-and-acute/

Comment: @gZerone: This character glyphs is not defined in the font you use. Thus Android provides a rendering of its own (either blank or some junk display). And I also confirm that Roboto font (Stock Android default font) do support this. Maybe you want to consider switching your font type. =(

Comment: @haike00: I 've changed the font already. Thank you. Please answer my question, I 'll mark it as acceptable.

Comment: As per your request. =p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The glyph (something that tell the machine how to draw a symbol) of the Unicode is not defined in the font in use.

Without the glyph, Android does not know how to render it correctly. In some Android version, you see it like square box whereas it is just a blank space in others.

System font is always safer to use in this case.
To unify your app display, you can use the Roboto font designed for Android since ICS.